# C# web Api2.0 - 405 Method Not Allowed [put]

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2

i try to make a web api on a table in DB get, post, delete methods works fine but i get **405 Method Not Allowed** when try to apply **Put** method by using **Fiddler**

here is code for post method:

```
[HttpPut]
        public void Put(int UserID, [FromBody] User obj)
        {
            var webApi = db.WebApis.Find(UserID);
            if (webApi != null)
            {
                webApi.Name = obj.Name;
                webApi.address = obj.address;
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
}
```

webApiConfig file :

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace WEbAPi
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                          name: "DatatApi",
                          routeTemplate: "data/{id}",
                          defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
                      );
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your PUT action?

Comment: sorry for that edited

Comment: Possibly the the UserId parameter could be an issue. Otherwise there's not much I can tell without seeing some client side code.

Answer (score 3):

Did you define a PUT method, and if so, please post it. Otherwise, your problem is that you're attempting to call PUT on a controller without a PUT method

EDIT:
Your id Property is named `UserID`, but in your route config you're specifying the third segment is `id`. Change your parameter to `id`

Comment: added in  the question

Comment: try changing UserID to id

Comment: You should mark this as the answer if that worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in your config folder you have the following code:

```
  <httpProtocol>
<customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
</customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Here is a very good article that explains how to troubleshoot your problem
[Troubleshooting 405 Error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/troubleshooting-http-405-errors-after-publishing-web-api-applications)